# xrdp only showing the background of servers screen w/o windows open and does not allowd any action

Tags: remote-desktop, raspberry-pi, xrdp

I'm trying to get remote control of RPI with xrdp via PC and via cellphone.
The result are the same I can only see the background of servers screen whith mouse cursor but can not do anythig.
Reentering 'Remote desktop connection' or the app or restarting the raspberry did not help.

**EDIT:**  Well now tried with different SD card and it works smoothly.
Must be some contradictable installations.
The question is still open.

**Hint:** That's not VNC.

**EDIT:** Another branch to this question: The above mentioned SD card will not enable connection when inserted into different RPI.The error code is 0x300005c and it says 'Unable to connect etc. Make sure the remote PC is turned on etc.'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that I was told that xrdp will give acces to RPIs desktop such as starting a program, editting a file etc' instead all I get from it is abserving the background of the desktop but not being able to do any action. I need remote **control**.